# Dropping "const int" qualifiers in template operator[]

Tags: c++, stl

I have looked at several post about const qualifiers, but I am not able to figure out how to fix this issue. I am building a class that is modeled after the STL map class, and I am using the STL set class as the base class:

```
template <class Key, class Value>
class map : public std::set <std::pair<Key, Value> > {
public:
    typedef std::set<std::pair<Key, Value> > parent;
    typedef typename std::set<std::pair<Key, Value> >::iterator iterator;

    // constructors
    map() : parent() {}
    map(map<Key, Value>& m) : parent(m) {}

    // definition for subscript operator
    Value& operator [] (const Key &);

    // overloaded methods from set
    void erase(Key&);
    void erase(iterator& itr) {
        parent::erase(itr);
    }

    int count(Key&);
    iterator find(Key&);
    iterator lower_bound(Key& k) {
        return parent::lower_bound(k);
    }

    iterator upper_bound(Key& k) {
        return parent::upper_bound(k);
    }

    // not found iterator
    iterator end() {
        return parent::end();
    }

};
```

The problem is with the operator[] overload function, which looks like:

```
template <class Key, class Value>
Value&  map<Key, Value>::operator[] (const Key& k) {
    std::pair<Key, Value> test;
    test.first = k;

    std::pair<iterator, bool> where = parent::insert(test);

    return (*(where.first)).second;
}
```

The compiler is giving me the error "...map.h:108:16: Binding of reference to type 'int' to a value of type 'const int' drops qualifiers". I realize that it's seeing that (*(where.first)).second is evaluated to a "const int" and I am returning it to an "int" because I have declared a map as:

```
map<std::string, int> mymap;
mymap["one"] = 1;
```

It appears that the `std::pair<...>` is being defined as `std::pair<std::string, const int>` instead of `std::pair<std::string, int>`. At least this is my conjecture. I must be missing something simple, but I am not seeing it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In general, avoid inheriting from `std` containers.  They aren't designed to be inherited from.  Use "has-a" instead of "is-a".  Second, your ordering on your `std::set` is wrong, in that `std::pair::operator<` is fully lexographic, and you do not want to order on `Value`.

Comment: In general that is true. But this was actually for an example that I am planning to use in a course based on a student question. I am not ordering on Value. I am returning the reference of the value to be placed by another value. But the comment below clarifies why I can not do that. So instead, I take a different approach. 'thanks.

Comment: No, the code above orders on first `Key`, then on `Value`.  If you modify `Value` in the `set`, your `operator[]` won't even find the `pair<Key, Value>` any more!  It would instead find a completely different entry.

Comment: Okay, So in a `set<T>` the type `T` is used for the `set::key_type` and `set::value_type`. In this case I was using `T = pair<Key, Value>`. So the `set::value_type` and `set::key_type` are `pair<Key, Value>`. The `.first` and `.second` are referring to the values stored in the `pair<Key, Value>` object. And so by changing the `.second` of the `pair` that would change the order. So I am thinking that I could create my own `pair` class that orders only on `.first` and then changing `.second` would not change the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `std::set` elements are immutable (otherwise you could arbitrarily modify them and mess up the ordering without the `set` knowing about it); this is enforced by its method returning const iterators.

Therefore, `*(where.first)` is `const`, and therefore so is `(*(where.first)).second`.  So you can't return a non-`const` reference to it.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I forgot that the keys/values are essentially the same in sets. I'll do it another way.

Comment: @CHardnett, that is true, however if you *know* that the operation you apply is going to preserve the order of the elements/key you are allowed to change the elements via `const_cast`. (for example you can multiply all numbers by a constant). As usual, casts should be used carefully and only when you *know* something that the compiler doesn't know.